# Amazon AWS EC2 SSH Login Through Putty on Windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

Ok, so I've read the tutorial here:
http://www.powercram.com/2009/07/connecting-to-aws-ec2-instance-linux.html

I created a keypair on Ec2, and ran it through puttygen, and tried to login via putty. I tried logging into the ip of the site, the url of the site, and the public DNS given to me by Amazon. I've tried logging in as root, ec2-user, ubuntu (even though I think its a fedora install, I'm just not sure because I just inherited this project). The name of the keypair on amazon's interface is hooper, so I tried logging in as that. Every time I get "server refused our key". I've read many peoples post on this problem, and none of the solutions seem to work for me. If any one has any other ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the instance is running under the keypair you think it is - you have to ensure the key PEM file you ran through PuttyGEN is the actual key that the instance is authenticated with.

Comment: i added a new keypair and used that one. Do I have to do something to authenticated with that instance? There is only one instance running.

Comment: Wait. I figured out what you were talking about. Each instance only has one keypair associated with it as best I can tell. Is there a way to switch the key pair, or do I have to restart the instance to do that?

Comment: You must use the PEM file associated with the keypair that the instance is actually running under - just creating another keypair won't work, because that's not the one the instance started with.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've contacted the old it guy, and he's getting me the file, and I should be golden from there.